# What is the one word description for someone who likes spicy food?

Tags: single-word-requests, food

If a bibliophile likes books, then what is the -phile word for someone who enjoys eating spicy food?

Comment: Full disclosure: made up on the spot. ***capsaiciphile***

Comment: I'd go with _masochist_.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry @Dan Bron, someone got there first: [Transcendental Capsaicinophilic Society](http://www.chetbacon.com/tcs/tcs.html)

Quoted in the Economist in 1998, I think a *capsaicinophile* is the closest you'll get, even if it's not yet in dictionaries.

Comment: +1, although you'll no doubt receive objections to the mishmash of Latin and Greek used to construct this neologism...

Comment: This works only if _spicy but not hot_ is a concept you can't embrace or you eat habenero peppers as some misguided sign of personal prowess.

Comment: People came up with [_spicyphile_](https://www.google.ca/search?biw=1920&bih=974&ei=ZTqYWqPxEYvAjwSasp_YDQ&q=%22spicyphile%22&oq=%22spicyphile%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...18962.19138.0.19370.2.2.0.0.0.0.77.146.2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.LS-2FJNRlOM) and [_spicy-ophile_](https://www.google.ca/search?biw=1920&bih=974&ei=YDqYWvWhEMjEjwTa3qioDg&q=%22spicy-ophile%22&oq=%22spicy-ophile%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3749.3749.0.4180.1.1.0.0.0.0.64.64.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.GVmoB7z--AM) even.

Comment: I suspect *karukeumophile* would do, if you wanted to stay all Greek. Spice = καρύκευμα.

Comment: The ancient Greeks didn't have a word for capsaicin or spicy American peppers; the modern Greek is Καψικόν or Τσίλι, basically *kapsikon* or *tsili*.

Comment: @Gnawme It does not bother me too much (language change and language influence are a natural process), but I thought it interesting to refer to the Wiki page, which lists some examples. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word

Answer (score -1):

Chiliphile is now used or spiceophile.

For example, from [A Taste of the Holidays: 9 Gifts for Your Favorite Foodie](https://www.edgemedianetwork.com/story.php?285028):

> The company hatched by two business school buds (Theo Lee and Mike Kim) longing for the flavors of their families' and one celebrity chef, Chris Oh ("Cutthroat Kitchen," "Knife Fight,""Great American Food Truck Race") features Korean style snacks as well as sweet, rich and, of course, spicy sauces to satisfy any **spice-ophile**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did not see any usage online of chilliphile to mean all spicy food and not just chilies.